# Is $(X,d)$ a metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces

$X = C_{[a,b]}^1$, $d(f,g) = \displaystyle\max_{x \in [a,b]} |f'(x) - g'(x)| + |f(a) - g(a)|$. Is $(X,d)$ a metric space?

> **My attempt:**
> These conditions $d(f,g) \geq 0$, $d(f,g) = 0$, $d(f,g) = d(g,f)$ are trivial
> We condider the last condition for a metric, that is $d(f,h) \leq d(f,g) + d(g,h), \forall f,g,h \in X$.
>
> $d(f,h) = \displaystyle\max_{x \in [a,b]} |f'(x) - h'(x)| + |f(a) - h(a)|$.
>
> We have $|f'(x) - h'(x)| = |f'(x) - g'(x) + g'(x) - h(x)| \leq |f'(x) -g'(x)|+|g'(x) - h'(x)|$,
>
> $|f'(x) - h'(x)| \leq |f'(x) -g'(x)|+|g'(x) - h'(x)| \Rightarrow \displaystyle\max_{x \in [a,b]} |f'(x) - h'(x)| \leq |f'(x) -g'(x)|+|g'(x) - h'(x)| \Rightarrow \displaystyle\max_{x \in [a,b]} |f'(x) - h'(x)| \leq \displaystyle\max_{x \in [a,b]} |f'(x) - g'(x)|+|g'(x) - h'(x)|$
>
> Similarly we conclude that $|f(a) - h(a)| \leq |f(a) - g(a)|+|g(a) - h(a)| \Rightarrow \displaystyle\max_{x \in [a,b]} |f(a) - h(a)| \leq \displaystyle\max_{x \in [a,b]} |f(a) - g(a)|+|g(a) - h(a)|$
>
> Hence, $\displaystyle\max_{x \in [a,b]} |f'(x) - h'(x)| + |f(a) - h(a)| \leq \displaystyle\max_{x \in [a,b]} |f'(x) - g'(x)| + |f(a) - g(a)| + \displaystyle\max_{x \in [a,b]} |g'(x) - h'(x)| + |g(a) - h(a)|$
>
> Thus, $d$ is a metric on $X$.
> Is my proof true? Thank all!

Comment: On the first implication I think you meant $\displaystyle\max_{x \in [a,b]} |f'(x) - h'(x)| \leq |f'(x) -g'(x)|+|g'(x) - h'(x)|$,  and the same with the second implication ($h'$ instead of $g'$)

Comment: Oh sorry, my fault

Comment: The implication that F.A. points out is incorrect. Also you shouldn't write $x$ here because it is confusing. On the one hand $x$ is kind of a function variable between $a$ and $b$ and on the other it is where you actually evaluate the function.

Comment: As counter example take $ h(x) = g(x) =0$, $f(x) = x^2$, $a=0$, $b=2$ and take your $x$ to be any value between 0 and 2 (exclusive)

Comment: Is "$d(f,g)=0$" in your list of conditions supposed to be "$d(f,g)=0\Leftrightarrow f=g$"? That's what mheldman is complaining about, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of those explicit calculations, I would find it easier to to keep the various pieces of the construction separate by proving in general:

> **Lemma 1.** If $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ are metric spaces then $$ d((x_1,y_2),(x_2,y_2)) = \max(d_X(x_1,x_2), d_Y(y_1,y_2)) $$ defines a metric on $X\times Y$.
>
> **Lemma 2.** If $(Z,d_Z)$ is a metric space and $\varphi: W\to Z$ is any *injective* map, then $$ d_W(w_1,w_2) = d_Z(\varphi(w_1),\varphi(w_2)) $$ defines a metric on $W$.

Then apply these with $X=\mathcal C_{[a,b]}^0$ with the sup-norm, $Y=\mathbb R$, $Z=X\times Y$, and $\varphi(f) = (f',f(a))$.

(You would need to prove that $\varphi$ is injective, but that's a simple analysis exercise).

Answer (score 0):

Is it true that if two functions have the same (continuous) first derivative and take on the same value at a point then they are the same function? This assertion I would not consider trivial. The rest of the argument looks fine, though.

Comment: For your assertion, $d(f,g)=0$ so it is trivial, my opinion

Comment: Functions $f$ and $g$ are usually considered to be equal if they take on the same value at every point in their common domain.In some cases, like when we develop a theory of Lebesgue integration, we acknowledge that the space $L^2$, for example, consists of equivalence classes of functions and then brush this detail under the rug thereafter. But I think that in your case you may not be dealing with equivalence classes but with the functions themselves.

Comment: The functions are in $C^1_{[a,b]}$ so the derivatives are continuous, as well as the functions themselves. No need to worry about equivalence classes.

Comment: @md2perpe I agree. All I'm saying is that the statement is nontrivial and the OP needs to verify it to have a complete argument.